# Trying to connect a hot water dispenser to dedicated water supply valve but the pre-installed copper line from the h2o dispenser won't reach

Tags: plumbing

I have an insinkerator hot water dispenser whose copper water line is too short to reach the dedicated water outlet. This particular outlet was installed for a filtered water system. The inlet valve is had a regular 3/8" connector. The copper tubing coming from the dispenser is 1/4". Is there anything wrong with getting a 3/8 x 3/8 water hose and adding a 3/8 to 1/4" reducer on one end then attaching that reducer to the copper line?

Comment: A photo would help

Answer (score 7):

That is what pipes and hoses and pipe fittings are made to do.

No, there's nothing wrong with that.

*You might be able to find a 3/8x1/4 inch hose and skip the reducer fitting, though.*